# How do I loop back to the first item in an Array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm sure this is very simple, but I'm using a button to go to the next item in an array and display it in a label. That much works just fine, however once the end of the array is reached the app crashes since there are no items left to display. How do I get it to go back to the first item? I've tried an If statement but had no luck.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var firstQuote = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBOutlet weak var quotesLabel: UILabel!

var quotes = ["","Quote 1", "Quote 2", "Quote 3"]

@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {    

firstQuote = firstQuote + 1
quotesLabel.text = quotes[firstQuote]     
    
}
}
```

This is the If Statement I tried

```
@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    

    
    if firstQuote < quotes.count{
    firstQuote = firstQuote + 1
    quotesLabel.text = quotes[firstQuote]
}

    if firstQuote == quotes.count{
    firstQuote = 0
    quotesLabel.text = quotes[firstQuote]
    }  
}
```

Comment: An `if` statement could have worked.  What did yours say?

Comment: @PhillipMills I just added the If statement I tried

Comment: Index is from 0 to count -1, not 0 to count. That's why you have an issue. Once you understand that, another way, would be to use modulo: `quotesLabel.text = quotes[firstQuote % quotes.count]`, or do it on `firstQuote`: `firstQuote = (firstQuote + 1) % quotes.count`

Comment: As others have said in different words, the problem is when `firstQuote` is equal to `quotes.count - 1`.  In that case, you add 1 and index past the end of the array.

Comment: I've gotten this to work! I also used i to add a "previous button" to see the previous quote. I got that to work as well but ran into a similar issue, except in trying to go from the first quote in the array to the last. I can post as a new question if that's the proper way to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common solution is to use `%` (the remainder operator) to wrap `firstQuote` back to 0 when it is equal to `quotes.count`:

```
firstQuote = (firstQuote + 1) % quotes.count
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var quotes = ["Quote 0","Quote 1", "Quote 2", "Quote 3"]
var quotesNum = 0

@IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    result.text = quotes[quotesNum]
}

@IBAction func incrementButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if quotesNum < quotes.count {
        quotesNum += 1

        if quotesNum == quotes.count {
            quotesNum = 0
        }

        result.text = quotes[quotesNum]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With This Code Beside Fixing Your Problem, You Can Understand How property observer  Can Work

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var quotes = ["Quote 0","Quote 1", "Quote 2", "Quote 3"]

var quotesNum: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        result.text = quotes[quotesNum]
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    result.text = quotes[quotesNum]
}

@IBAction func incrementButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if quotesNum < quotes.count - 1 {
        
        if quotesNum == quotes.count - 1 {
            quotesNum = 0
        } else {
            quotesNum += 1
            
        }
    } else {
        quotesNum = 0
    }
}
```